# ask a server to not gzip content

Tags: node.js, http

Is it possible with an http request header to ask the server *not* to gzip content?

I'm using node.js `request.get` library to make an API call and it appears the content is coming back as gzipped.

Its only a problem with 1 api (i call several) and I'm thinking maybe their server is misconfigured. But I wanted to try asking the server for a non-gzipped version.

Here is the response I'm getting:

```
GET https://www.itbit.com/api/feeds/ticker/XBTUSD
4R�&HTpȇ��{3y�L�3��SJ)$�Qj��)�w\d�P�����('t]{�d@�������?� �ŔŅ�2�1Y��_�-X%�uS��}��Y���`���gN?
�-sP��rr6�.셢$�h��]������h�>�����<]@�mx-�����d ��鑈�`��+fos�r��%�����~G�c���E)���̓5pqXK�h�S����<��,M�F�P�n�'��@��+@��]琛����Ʒ{q���܀�6u*�lygnؓ�������z��ë>X�� �rS).����s!Z�U�"Fg��:zL   �����mx�W�_ѯ���^�
<l��ۊp?�t��H�1ǎ�e-��zCw�@�e�4�r�ke�z����zN��o�8����5�������\B<3��HL~g!�I��ȥ��.贡h_�aE�]X~��E����_���/7���h      Ia�����3���H:\�Âi����l��2�;]w;ގ:��\���s���(�4�hV咸�q�/g�v�
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a very strange server indeed.

This seems to prevent it from sending back gzipped content:

```
request({
  url     : 'https://www.itbit.com/api/feeds/ticker/XBTUSD',
  headers : { 'User-Agent' : '' }
}, ...);
```

(or some other random `User-Agent` header; it might be caching requests based on certain HTTP headers, and randomizing those headers may prevent it from serving already-cached gzipped responses)

Comment: @chovy since it's most likely a misconfiguration of the server, chances are that it may stop working at any time! @ loganfsmyth's solution about unzipping the content yourself is something you should still consider implementing

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I'm understanding your problem correctly, you can explicitly provide a value for the [Accept-Encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.3) header in your HTTP `GET` request.

```
request({
  url: '...',
  headers: {
    'Accept-Encoding': 'identity'
  }
}, function(err, res, body){

});
```

This assumes that the server you are requesting from respects the `Accept-Encoding` header. If it doesn't, then your only option would be to just unzip the content.

```
var zlib = require('zlib');

var req = request.get(...);
req.on('response', function(res){
    var stream;
    if (res.headers['content-encoding'] === 'gzip'){
        stream = res.pipe(zlib.createGunzip());
    } else {
        stream = res;
    }

    var chunks = [];
    stream.on('readable', function(){
      var chunk;
      while ((chunk = stream.read()) !== null) chunks.push(chunk);
    });
    stream.on('end', function(){
       var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);

       // Do what you'd normally do.
    });
});
```

This is how you would conditionally unzip a request based on the content encoding. That said, this API looks pretty inconsistent, since running this with the URL you gave returns a stack trace. As @robertklep pointed out, they seem to do some user-agent checking too, so it seems like this API isn't really designed for public consumption.

Comment: what would `identity` be here?

Comment: `identity` meaning to not use any content encoding when transferring the content, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function

Comment: still getting gzipped content back.

Comment: i updated question with api call and response I'm getting. Can you get this to work perhaps?

Comment: I filed a bug with them. hopefully they just fix the problem.